# Look for first cell with certain value in column, then insert 3 rows above

Tags: excel, vba, insert, row

I work on a spreadsheet every morning and need to automate the following in a VBA macro:

In column AE, look for first value greater than zero, then insert 3 rows above the row containing that specific cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set ws = ActiveSheet    'Adjust to be the correct worksheet if necessary

    With Intersect(ws.UsedRange, ws.Columns("AE"))
        On Error Resume Next
        lRow = Evaluate("=MATCH(1,INDEX((ISNUMBER(" & .Address(External:=True) & "))*(" & .Address(External:=True) & ">0),),0)")
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    If lRow > 0 Then
        ws.Rows(lRow).Resize(3).Insert
    Else
        MsgBox "No values in column AE found to be greater than 0."
    End If

End Sub
```